# Does Azure DevOps Server 2020 support multi layer PR approvals?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-repos

Suppose a PR is sent that contains 2 kinds of changes:

- Some metadata updates

  - Have required reviewers
- Business code

  - Does not have required reviewers

The problem is that if a metadata required reviewer approves the PR, it can be completed right away without waiting for the business logic reviewer.

This is not good. An ideal solution would be if every piece of business code has a well defined required reviewer, but alas - it is currently not possible in our code.

Is it possible to configure PR approvals so that metadata approval would not be used to complete the PR if the business logic has not been approved by anyone?